# Delphi xe8 deployment file

Tags: delphi-xe8

Bom pessoal estou utilizando o Delphi XE8 Multi-Device, Eu gostaria de anexar um arquivo imagem.jpg no projeto e poder usar no android, Eu olhei no site da embarcadero e lá diz como fazer então eu fiz: selecionei o arquivo coloquei em assets\internal , E fiz a recuperação para usar utilizando: TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'imagem.jpg'); Como é mostrado no site da embarcadero, Porem aparecer o erro:

Loading bitmap failed (/data/data/com.embarcadero.Project4/files/imagem.jpg).
Ou seja diz que ele não encontrou o arquivo... Alguém já teve o mesmo problema?? O estranho é que fiz conforme o site da embarcadero mostra e mesmo assim não tive sucesso.

O link que usei como referencia para fazer foi: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Creating_an_Android_App#Loading_and_Deploying_Files.   Na parte: Loading and Deploying Files.